# Cannot create a table using "NOT EXISTS"

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite

I have an error

> near "NOT": syntax error

while executing such query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SAD_NHR_32_4 (ID number, 
                                         TIME1970 number, 
                                         VAL number, 
                                         STATE number)
```

I use sqlite3_exec call to do this. Sqlite version is 3.7.7.1. Project compiled with g++ in SLES 10 SP4 x64.

What may cause such a result?

Comment: The query works fine on `sqlite>` prompt with no errors.  Are you missing something else?

Comment: That's the most strange about that error. Query works well using `sqlite>`, so I think the problem is somehow related with type of system I use, or something else. Anyway - according to syntax rules given here: [link](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) the query is correct.

Comment: Could you show us your actual code?

Comment: Problem solved - sqlite `make install` copied files to `/lib` instead of `/lib64`. So, some old version included in system start package was used.